# List.Count() throws ArgumentOutOfRangeException on the DevOps build, but not locally

Tags: c#, azure, selenium, azure-devops

So I ran into a very weird and confusing problem today: 
I'm writing Selenium Tests for an online book store. For one of the backlist pages, I've written a test that simply creates an entry.

To see if it worked, I process the list of entries on the index page into a List and read the List.Count() before and after the operation to see if it has increased.

This runs perfectly in my environment. But: On the Azure DevOps build, it tells me

> Test method
>   MyProject.Admin.Test.SeleniumTest.NewsletterBlacklist.CreateBlacklistEntryTest.CreateBlacklistEntry
>   threw exception:  System.ArgumentOutOfRangeException: Index was out of
>   range. Must be non-negative and less than the size of the collection.
>   Parameter name: index

The stack trace says

> at
>   System.ThrowHelper.ThrowArgumentOutOfRangeException(ExceptionArgument
>   argument, ExceptionResource resource)
>   at
>   MyProject.Admin.Test.PageObjectModel.Configuration.NewsletterBlacklistPage.get_BlacklistedNewsletterList()
>   in
>   C:\agent_work\8\s\MyProject.Admin.Test\PageObjectModel\Configuration\NewsletterBlacklistPage.cs:line
>   66
>   at
>   MyProject.Admin.Test.SeleniumTest.NewsletterBlacklist.CreateBlacklistEntryTest.CreateBlacklistEntry()
>   in
>   C:\agent_work\8\s\MyProject.Admin.Test\SeleniumTest\NewsletterBlacklist\CreateBlacklistEntryTest.cs:line
>   54

This has me confused, since AFAIK List.Count() should just return 0 when it tries to count the entries of an empty list. List.Any() doesn't work either.
This error occurs in two of my tests, the rest of the tests that use this kind of validation all don't run into this error.

**Class CreateBlacklistEntryTest**
This is the snippet where I try using Count() (This is post-tried-workaround where I wanted to see if using Any() would have a different outcome):

```
var countBefore = 0;
if (blacklistPage.BlacklistedNewsletterList.Any())
{
    countBefore = blacklistPage.BlacklistedNewsletterList.Count();
}

blacklistPage.CreateBlacklistItem($"{Guid.NewGuid()}".Substring(24));
System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(1000);

var countAfter = blacklistPage.BlacklistedNewsletterList.Count();

if (countAfter != countBefore + 1)
{
     Assert.Fail("No Blacklist item was added, or too many.");
}
```

**Class NewsletterBlacklistPage**
This is the code that creates an empty List and tries to fill it using the Data from the DOM tree on the index page:

```
public IList<NewsletterBlacklistModel> BlacklistedNewsletterList
    {
        get
        {
            List<NewsletterBlacklistModel> result = new List<NewsletterBlacklistModel>();

            // we parse with agility pack, selenium would take too long
            var html = new HtmlAgilityPack.HtmlDocument();
            html.LoadHtml(Browser.WebDriver.PageSource);

            var table = html.DocumentNode.SelectSingleNode("//table[@class='table table-striped']");

            // each row in table is one list entry
            foreach (var row in table.SelectNodes("tbody/tr"))
            {
                var blacklistItem = new Model.NewsletterBlacklistModel();
                blacklistItem.Cover = row.ChildNodes.Nodes().ToList()[0].InnerText;
                blacklistItem.Ean = row.ChildNodes.Nodes().ToList()[1].InnerText;

                // blacklistItem.EditButton = Browser.FindElementWait(By.XPath("//button[@id='btn_edit']"));
                blacklistItem.DeleteButton = Browser.FindElementWait(By.XPath("//button[@id='btn_delete']"));
                result.Add(blacklistItem);
            }

            return result;
        }
    }
```

Any pointers? I've been trying new workarounds and googling solutions for hours.

Thanks in advance,
Carni

Comment: Please could you show the complete stack trace rather than just the message? I wouldn't be surprised if the problem was actually while you're building the list (e.g. in `row.ChildNodes.Nodes().ToList()[0]`) rather than when obtaining its count.

Comment: hi @JonSkeet , is this better? As I'm writing this, the server is building another version with your suggested problem hopefully solved.

Comment: Right, that certainly shows that the problem is within the `BlacklistedNewsletterList` property accessor, *not* calling `Count` on the result of it. You should look at line 66 of NewsletterBlacklistPage.cs - we can't tell what that is, but you should be able to.

Comment: @JonSkeet Actually, I included the relevant code in the post: the second snippet is from NewsletterBlacklistPage.cs - I forgot to indicate that, my bad. Anyway, this is line 66 of that class:  
  
`List<NewsletterBlacklistModel> result = new List<NewsletterBlacklistModel>();`

Comment: Yes, I'm aware you included the code, but without knowing which was line 66, it was hard to say where exactly the problem was. I doubt that that was line 66 when the problem occurred, as that line can't create that exception. I would guess you've changed the code since getting that stack trace.

Comment: @JonSkeet
I did change the code, but I'm telling you this was the line that the server marked as the source of the error, for whatever reason. The actual error, however, was was on line 79:  `
`blacklistItem.Ean = row.ChildNodes.Nodes().ToList()[1].InnerText;`
...just like you initially said. When I tried correcting that initally, I added a check if there were any ROWS in the list instead of columns. As always, you're a god Jon. problem solved. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Question answered by [Jon Skeet.](https://stackoverflow.com/users/22656/jon-skeet)
The error was not on the marked line, but on the line

```
blacklistItem.Ean = row.ChildNodes.Nodes().ToList()[1].InnerText;
```

Where I tried to access a column in the table that's not existent if the table is empty.
I simply had to check if the table had any columns before accessing them.